# Erasing vector element crashing the program

Tags: c++

Why the follwoing code is failing ?

```
typedef vector<SOCKET /*socket*/> UIConnection;

UIConnection::iterator itrUICon;

for ( itrUICon = m_ListUIConnection.begin();itrUICon != m_ListUIConnection.end();itrUICon++)
{
    if (*itrUICon == nSock)
    {           
        itrUICon = m_ListUIConnection.erase(itrUICon);          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably because you are erasing the last item in the vector and then incrementing `itrUICon` in the increment part of the `for` statement when it is already equal to `.end()`.

Prefer using the `erase()/std::remove()` idiom or at least move the increment out of the `for` statement and only perform it if you didn't preform an `erase`.

Comment: charles will this work for map as well.typedef map<unsigned long /*mac id */ ,int /*socket*/> GatewayConnection;

Comment: @Chris_vr: For `std::remove` won't work for associative containers because they preserve order. You can do `mp.erase(it++);` instead because erasing an element from a map doesn't invalidate any iterators other than those pointing to the element removed.

Answer (score 6):

You must remove the `++itrUICon` in the `for` instruction.

```
UIConnection::iterator itrUICon;

for ( itrUICon = m_ListUIConnection.begin();itrUICon != m_ListUIConnection.end(); )
{
    if (*itrUICon == nSock)
    {           
        itrUICon = m_ListUIConnection.erase(itrUICon);          
    }
    else ++itrUICon;
}
```

Comment: Dang, right! I remember that one from my last project actually.

Comment: @Simone: Probably a random drive-by. I received one at about the same time as yours.

Comment: @Charles I see. I didn't know that things like that happens on SO too

Comment: Calling `erase` on a vector [invalidates all iterator and references to elements after position](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) - can you explain why your code works?

Comment: @Martin from your link: "Return value: A random access iterator pointing to the new location of the element that followed the last element erased by the function call, which is the vector end if the operation erased the last element in the sequence.".

Comment: martin Will erase()/std::remove() idiom  work for map typedef map<unsigned long /*mac id */ ,int /*socket*/> GatewayConnection;

Comment: @Chris_vr no, map::erase() returns void. You will need to modify your code

Comment: @Simone: Ah. I somehow missed that you are reassigning `itrUICon`, so there's no problem with invalidation.